# Modal popup not generating postback to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-ajax

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender  runat="server" 
         id="ModalPopupExtender1"
         cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" okcontrolid="btnOkay" 
         targetcontrolid="Button1" popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
         drag="true" 
         backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG"
        />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test Modal Popup" 
    onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Post Back" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Nothing has happened yet..."></asp:Label>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Canel" 
                    onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnOkay" runat="server" Text="Okay" onclick="btnOkay_Click" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So I am trying to get the Label to have the contents of what the user typed in the textbox inside the modal popup. Right now the `btnOkay` is not causing this to work.

`.cs` file:

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
protected void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    TextBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "";
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "You clicked the button";
}
```

I do not want the page to post back at all, but just to update the hidden labels on the page once information is entered. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Alright, this should do the trick I think.

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" id="ModalPopupExtender1" targetcontrolid="Button1"
    popupcontrolid="Panel1" drag="true" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG"  />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test Modal Popup" /><br />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Canel" onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnOkay" runat="server" Text="Okay" onclick="btnOkay_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Nothing has happened yet..." />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = ""; 
}

protected void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    up.Update();
}
```

Comment: No I want the text box in the popup to populate a label on the page when the ok button is clicked. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: and you want the textbox to be filled out from inside the modalpopup?

Comment: So inside the popup I want there to be a text box where the user inputs information such as their name. Then click ok in the popup and the popup goes away. Then the labels on the page are showing the inputted name.

Comment: Edited the code in my response. That should do what you're wanting.

Comment: This works great and exactly how I want it for the first time you enter it. If the user has made a mistake I want them to be able to click "Test modal popup" again and enter new text that overrights the old text. This does not work in your situation.

Comment: It's working for me that way using the code I put above. Did you make any modifications?

Comment: @JonathanO let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1699/discussion-between-abney317-and-jonathan-o)